# Resources on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I just want to know how this works out. I made a folder and placed it inside of my xcode project. I placed images inside of these folders. What I am wondering is if even though this folder is on my xcode project is it calling to all the resources inside to where they are on the computer instead of being in the project? Because when I edit an image on my computer it is updating it inside the project as well. I just don't want to submit this project when it is done and find out that none of the images went with it. I suppose it isn't like android where I can just drag and drop the images in the res/drawable and that app has the image to itself?

Any info on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what you put in the Resources folder will get included in your Bundle (With Xcode 4, the Resources folder may now be called "Supporting Files").

If in doubt, you can check the target settings, and you should see all the files that are being included in the bundle:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They will be embedded. I similarly placed a subfolder under the resources folder, and it shipped with my application just fine. As long as it's under there you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

resocreate a folder either in the resource or in the class file add the newfolder and drag and drop your images,that will be added in your folder